# Teradata - Insert new rows only

Tags: sql, teradata

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this insert statement?
I am trying to insert new rows into the USERS_AND_USAGE_STG2 table, from PERMS_STG2 table, if the combination of USER_ID, OBJECT, and DATE is not already present.

The USERS_AND_USAGE_STG2 has a unique key of DATE, USER_ID & OBJECT.
When I run the statement below, it errors with "INSERT Failed. 2801:  Duplicate unique prime key error in....."
**I realize that Staging tables usually don't have Unique Keys, but it is telling me that my "Insert if not exists" isn't working correctly.

```
INSERT INTO WORK1.USERS_AND_USAGE_STG2 
(EFF_DT
 ,USER_ID
 ,SP_ADDED_DT
 ,OBJECT
 ,ACCESS_IS_ACTIVE)

 SELECT 
 EFF_DT
 ,USER_ID
 ,EFF_DT
 ,COMBO_NAME
 ,'Y'
 FROM WORK1.PERMS_STG2 P
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT USER_ID, OBJECT
                    FROM WORK1.USERS_AND_USAGE_STG2
                    WHERE USER_ID = P.USER_ID
                        AND OBJECT = P.COMBO_NAME
                        AND EFF_DT = P.EFF_DT);
```

Comment: Perhaps you have duplicates in `WORK1.PERMS_STG2` on that `USER_ID, OBJECT, EFF_DT` key? Do you get results back when you run `SELECT * FROM WORK1.PERMS_STG2 QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID, EFF_DT, COMBO_NAME) > 1;` ? If so, then your `PERMS_STG2` table has duplicates that you will have to address (pick one or the other and insert).

Comment: Do NULLs exist in those columns? Btw, after fixing the problem you might try MERGE WHEN NOT FOUND instead

Comment: @JNevill, Great suggestion and I was a little worried.  I tried this and thankfully returned no rows:

    SELECT *
    FROM USERS_AND_USAGE_STG2
    QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID
    ,OBJECT
    ,EFF_DT) >1

Comment: @dnoeth, No nulls.  I thought about MERGE, but I don't have any data to update, just inserts.

Comment: Perhaps you can identify the duplicates with something like `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 
 EFF_DT
 ,USER_ID
 ,EFF_DT
 ,COMBO_NAME
 ,'Y'
 FROM WORK1.PERMS_STG2 P
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT USER_ID, OBJECT
                    FROM WORK1.USERS_AND_USAGE_STG2
                    WHERE USER_ID = P.USER_ID
                        AND OBJECT = P.COMBO_NAME
                        AND EFF_DT = P.EFF_DT) UNION ALL SELECT EFF_DT
 ,USER_ID
 ,SP_ADDED_DT
 ,OBJECT
 ,ACCESS_IS_ACTIVE FROM WORK1.USERS_AND_USAGE_STG2) dt QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER PARTITION BY (USER_ID, EFF_DT, COMBO_NAME) > 1;`

Comment: Are you sure that the unique PI columns in `USERS_AND_USAGE_STG2` are the ones you are using in you not exists clause?

Comment: You can do an Insert-MERGE without update.

Comment: @JNevill, it was a dupe problem.  If you want to chagne one of your comments to an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.  Regardless, thanks!

Comment: @dnoeth, I never thought of that.  All the examples had Updates, so I assumed it was required.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code above is/was correct.  I had a problem with my source data.  @JNevill deserves the credit for pointing that out.